# resizing UIImage the fastest and efficient way

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimage

I wanted to resize a UIImage to a certain width and height keeping the proportion in place. The simplest way to do this is:

```
 CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(726, 521);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage * newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Does the method above have any drawbacks in terms of image quality and the time it takes? What is a better way than the method above?

EDITED:

How about this one:

```
- (UIImage *)imageByScalingProportionallyToSize:(CGSize)targetSize {

    UIImage *sourceImage = self;
    UIImage *newImage = nil;

    CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;
    CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
    CGFloat height = imageSize.height;

    CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
    CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;

    CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;
    CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
    CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;

    CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize) == NO) {

        CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
        CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

        if (widthFactor < heightFactor) 
            scaleFactor = widthFactor;
        else
            scaleFactor = heightFactor;

        scaledWidth  = width * scaleFactor;
        scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

        // center the image

        if (widthFactor < heightFactor) {
            thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5; 
        } else if (widthFactor > heightFactor) {
            thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
        }
    }


    // this is actually the interesting part:

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);

    CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
    thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
    thumbnailRect.size.width  = scaledWidth;
    thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

    [sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if(newImage == nil) NSLog(@"could not scale image");


    return newImage ;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a performance sample of [Image Resizing Techniques](https://nshipster.com/image-resizing/) the score was

- 0.1420 UIKit
- 0.1722 Core Graphics
- 0.1616 Image I/O
- 2.4983 Core Image
- 2.3126 vImage

so the fastest and simplest way is:

```swift
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
let resized = renderer.image { (context) in
    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
}
```

[Resize a UIImage the right way](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) is from 2009 but contains useful talk about interpolation quality and preserving the aspect ratio.

---

Additionally, to preserve the ratio within a max size:

```swift
let image: UIImage = ...
let maxSize = CGSize(width: 726, height: 521)
let newSize = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: image.size, insideRect: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: maxSize)).size
let resized = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: newSize).image { _ in
    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize))
}
```

To change the pixels per point density (default is the ppp of the current screen):

```swift
let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
format.scale = 1
UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: newSize, format: format)
...
```

Comment: +1 That's an excellent article on resizing an image and highlights how you can easily do it wrong if you aren't careful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way:

```
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
    CGSize sacleSize = CGSizeMake(10, 10); // scale image to 10 x 10
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sacleSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, sacleSize.width, sacleSize.height)];
    UIImage * resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

**resizedImage** is a new image.