# Resizing a Screenshot Taken With UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, image-resizing

In an app I'm developing, the customer enters in some personal information and signs a box on the screen. I then programmatically screenshot the the full view and convert it to base64.

This is working fine, however, due to the size of the image it takes approximately 15 seconds to convert it to base64 and send it to an API server. The image size at full quality is the same size as the iPad Air resolution (1536x2048).

Once saved on the server as a PNG, the image weighs in at around 410kb.

I want to resize the image capture down to 768x1024 (half of what it is) without losing clarity. I think this will save both time and storage space.

I'm currently taking the "screenshot" using the following function:

```
func screenCaptureAndGo() {
    //Create the UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, view.opaque, 0.0)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    imageDataString = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
}
```

I left out the API server stuff as it's not really relevant.

Comment: Isn't this boils down to simply resizing a UIImage? If so, check this answer: 
 [resizing UIImage the fastest and efficient way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522159/resizing-uiimage-the-fastest-and-efficient-way)

Comment: I'll look into that once I get home from work. It looks promising, however, the images used in those examples are pulled from the filesystem. Probably isn't a huge different, I'd imagine.

Comment: I ended up just using the Scale property. It didn't work the first time, which is why I didn't think to use it again, but after toying with it I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using the Scale property. It didn't work the first time, which is why I didn't think to use it again, but after toying with it I got it to work.

I'm using 0.7 as the scale amount, and the images now clock in at 100kb, and it takes 4 seconds to convert and send the base64 string.