# Change size of UIImage to desired size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am using this code to change the size of images.

```
- (UIImage *)scaledImage:(UIImage *)image size:(CGSize)size {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 1.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

I am currently in need to change the size of 100 images at runtime but this code causes delay. The loading time is much.
Is there any faster way to resize the UIImage?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [resizing UIImage the fastest and efficient way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522159/resizing-uiimage-the-fastest-and-efficient-way)

Comment: This will not retain your aspect ratio of your image

Comment: I am not concerned about the aspect ratio actually. I just want to some other way that can do that same process but takes less time.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,75,75);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( rect.size );
[yourCurrentOriginalImage drawInRect:rect];
UIImage *picture1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(picture1);
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: drawInRect method takes a noticable delay to execute (like for 100 images about 1-2 seconds) when we try to convert lots of images at a time, basically in a loop. So, this doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

```
'- (UIImage *)scaledImage:(UIImage *)image size:(CGSize)size {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0, size.width,size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( size );
    [image drawInRect:rect];
    UIImage *picture1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(picture1);
    UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    return img;
}'
```

Comment: drawInRect method takes a noticable delay to execute (like for 100 images about 1-2 seconds) when we try to convert lots of images at a time, basically in a loop. So, this doesnt work for me